# ¿Cómo resuelvo " 'i' was not declared in this scope" con plantillas y herencia multiple?

Tags: c++, herencia, template

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  5.11 Vector Herencia Multiple Polimorfismo Sobrecarga
//
//  Created by Fernando Sánchez on 31/12/00.
//  Copyright © 2000 Fernando Sánchez. All rights reserved.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

const int MAX=50;
static int CORTE;

template <class T>
class comandos_basicos
{
public:
    void alv();
    void color();
    void limpiar_pantalla();
    void limpiar_buffer();
};

template <class T>
void comandos_basicos<T>::alv()
{
    exit(0);
};

template <class T>
void comandos_basicos<T>::color()
{
    system("Color 0A");
};
template <class T>
void comandos_basicos<T>::limpiar_pantalla()
{
    system("cls");
};
template <class T>
void comandos_basicos<T>::limpiar_buffer()
{
    cin.get();
};

template <class T>
class Vector //: public comandos_basicos<T>
{
public:
    T tamano;     //Determina el tamanio del vector
    T *vector;    //Pues el vector :v
    T i;          //un contador
    T j;          //otro contador
    T auxiliar;   //ayuda a ordenar el vector
    T numero;     //Ayuda a buscar el numero
    char respuesta; //Tonteria de validacion
//public:
    Vector();
    void llenado();
    void obtener_tamano();

    //metodos con polimorfismo
    void crear_vector(); //original
    void ordenamiento();

    void impresion();
    //void ordenamiento();

    ~Vector();
};
//Constructor
template <class T>
Vector<T>::Vector()
{
    //system("cls");
    cout << "Este programa contiene una clase Vector\nla cual contiene a su vez un constructor\nasi que empezare construyendo un vector para poder operar\nquieras o no\n"<<endl;
    cout << "VECTOR NUMERICO DINAMICO \n\n";
    cout << "Tamanio del vector: ";
    cin  >> tamano;

    vector = new T[tamano];
    cout << endl;

};

//Destructor
template <class T>
Vector<T>::~Vector()
{
    cout<<"Y bien, este es el destructor :3 \n como te lo dije\n gracias"<<endl;
    delete vector;
};

template <class T>
void Vector<T>::llenado()
{
    //llenado del vector

    for(i=1 ; i <= tamano ; i++)
    {
        cout << "Vect["<< i << "]= ";
        cin  >> *(vector+i);

        for(int j=1 ; j<i ; j++)
        {
            if(*(vector+j) == *(vector+i))
            {
                cout<<"Error, este dato ya existe, ingresa otro :v"<<endl;
                i--;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
// sobrecarga, declarado antes
template <class T>
void Vector<T>::ordenamiento()
{
    cout<<endl<<"\tNo ordenare aun, quiero que veas el vector desordenado jajaja \n(metodo ordenar clase base)"<<endl;
}

// clase derivada HERENCIA MULTIPLE
template <class T>
class operaciones_vector: public Vector<T>//, public comandos_basicos <T>
{

protected:
    T vect [MAX];
    T aux,dato;
    T k,cont,op,opc2;
    T izq, centro,der;
    T pivote;
    T *ptr_i, *ptr_j;

    /*T tamano;     //Determina el tamanio del vector
    T *vector;    //Pues el vector :v
    T i;          //un contador
    T j;          //otro contador
    T auxiliar;   //ayuda a ordenar el vector
    T numero;     //Ayuda a buscar el numero
    char respuesta; //Tonteria de validacion*/

public:
    void llenado(){};
    void crear_vector(); // polimorfismo :3

    void alv(){};

    void ordenamiento();
    void burbuja();
    void seleccion();
    void intercambiarseleccion();
    void insercion();
    void shell();
    void monticulos();
    void intercambiar_monticulos(int vect[MAX],int i,int j);
    void filtrado_desc_monticulos(int vect[MAX],int i,int tam);
    void mergesort();
    void ord_intercalacion(int vect[MAX], int aux[MAX], int izq, int der);
    void intercalar(int vect[MAX], int aux[MAX], int izq, int centro, int der);
    void quicksort();
    void ord_rapida(int vect[MAX], int izq, int der);
    void ord_ma();
    void ord_indi();
    void burbuja_mejorada();

    void Mostrar();
    void impresion();

    void busqueda();
    void busqueda_secuencial();
    void busqueda_binaria();

    void menu();

    void color(T n);
};

template <class T>
void operaciones_vector<T>::color(T n)
{
    system("Color 0A");
}

template <class T>
void operaciones_vector<T>::ordenamiento()
{
    cout<<"\n1)Ordenamiento Burbuja"<<endl
    <<"2)Ordenamiento por Seleccion"<<endl
    <<"3)Ordenamiento por Insercion"<<endl
    <<"4)Ordenamiento Shell"<<endl
    <<"5)Ordenamiento por monticulos (Heapsort)"<<endl
    <<"6)Ordenamiento por Intercalacion (mergesort)"<<endl
    <<"7)Ordenamiento rapido (quicksort)"<<endl
    <<"8)Ordenamiento utilizando multiples algoritmos"<<endl
    <<"9)Ordenamiento Indirecta de los datos"<<endl
    <<"10)Ordenamiento por Burbuja Mejorada"<<endl
    <<"11)Regresar"<<endl
    <<"\tOPCION: ";
    cin>>opc2;

    switch(opc2)
    {
        case 1:
            crear_vector();
            burbuja();
            Mostrar();
            cin.get();
            break;

        case 2:
            crear_vector();
            seleccion();
            Mostrar();
            cin.get();
            break;

        case 3:
            crear_vector();
            insercion();
            Mostrar();
            cin.get();
            break;

        case 4:
            crear_vector();
            shell();
            Mostrar();
            cin.get();
            break;

        case 5:
            crear_vector();
            monticulos();
            Mostrar();
            cin.get();
            break;

        case 6:
            crear_vector();
            mergesort();
            Mostrar();
            cin.get();
            break;

        case 7:
            crear_vector();
            mergesort();
            quicksort();
            Mostrar();
            cin.get();
            break;

        case 8:
            crear_vector();
            insercion();
            ord_ma();
            Mostrar();
            cin.get();

        case 9:
            crear_vector();
            ord_indi();
            Mostrar();
            cin.get();
            break;

        case 10:
            crear_vector();
            burbuja_mejorada();
            Mostrar();
            cin.get();
            break;
    }
}

template <class T>
void operaciones_vector<T>::impresion()
{
    cout<<"I m p r i m i r"<<endl;
    for(i=1 ; i <= tamano ; i++)
    {
        cout << "Vect["<<i<<"]= " << *(vector+i) << endl;
    }
}

template <class T>
void operaciones_vector<T>::Mostrar()
{
    cout<<"Contenido del vector ORDENADO"<<endl;
    for(i = 1 ; i<= tamano ; i++)
    {
        cout<<"\t"<<vect[i];
    }
    cout<<endl;
    system("Pause");
}

template <class T>
void operaciones_vector<T>::busqueda()
{
    cout<<"\n\n1)Busqueda Secuencial"<<endl
    <<"2)Busqueda binaria"<<endl
    <<"3)Regresar"<<endl
    <<"\tOPCION: ";
    cin>>opc2;
    cout<<"\n\n";
    switch(opc2)
    {
        case 1:
            crear_vector();
            busqueda_secuencial();
            break;
        case 2:
            crear_vector();
            busqueda_binaria();
            break;
    }
}
// polimorfismo sobrecarga

template <class T>
void operaciones_vector<T>::crear_vector()//este pedazo maravilloso crea el auxiliar :3
{
    for(i = 1 ; i <= tamano ; i++)
    {
        vect[i]=*(vector+i);
    }
    cout<<"Contenido del vector ANTES de ordenar."<<endl;
    for(i = 1 ; i<= tamano ; i++)
    {
        cout<<"\t"<<vect[i];
    }
    cout<<endl;
    //system("Pause");

};


template <class T>
void operaciones_vector<T>::burbuja()
{
    for(i = 1 ; i<= tamano ; i++)
    {
        for(j = 1 ; j <= tamano ; j++)
        {
            if(vect[j] > vect[i])
            {
                aux=(vect[j]);
                vect[j]=vect[j+1];
                vect[j+1]=aux;
            }
        }
    }
}

template <class T>
void operaciones_vector<T>::seleccion()
{
    for(i=1;i<=tamano-1;i++)
    {
        for(k=i,j=i+1;j<=tamano;j++)
        {
            if (vect[j]<vect[k])
            {
                k=j;
                if(k!=i)
                {
                    intercambiarseleccion();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

template <class T>
void operaciones_vector<T>::intercambiarseleccion()
{
    aux=vect[i];
    vect[i]=vect[j];
    vect[j]=aux;
}

template <class T>
void operaciones_vector<T>::insercion()
{
    for(i=1;i<tamano;i++)
    {
        aux=vect[i];
        j= i-1;

        while((j>=0)&&(aux<vect[j]))
        {
            vect[j+1]=vect[j];
            j--;
        }
        vect[j+1]=aux;
    }
}

template <class T>
void operaciones_vector<T>::shell()
{
    int incr=tamano/2;
    do
    {
        for(i=incr;i<=tamano;i++)
        {
            aux = vect[i];
            j=i-incr;

            while((j>=0)&&(aux<vect[j]))
            {
                vect[j+incr]=vect[j];
                j-=incr;
            }
            vect[j+incr]=aux;
        }
        incr/=2;
    }
    while(incr>0);
}

//Ordena de forma descendente
template <class T>
void operaciones_vector<T>::filtrado_desc_monticulos(int vect[MAX],int i,int tam)
{
    //Queremos que se respete el orden MAX del monticulo
    cout<<"Este metodo ordena de forma descendente :v"<<endl;
    aux=vect[i];
    int hijo=2*i;

    if((hijo<tamano)&&(vect[hijo+1]>vect[hijo]))
    {
        hijo++;
    }
    while((hijo<=tamano)&&(aux<vect[hijo]))
    {
        //Elijo bien el hijo
        if((hijo<tamano)&&(vect[hijo+1]>vect[hijo]))
        {
            hijo++;
        }
        vect[i] = vect[hijo];
        i=hijo;
        hijo=2*i;
    }
    vect[i]=aux;
}

template <class T>
void operaciones_vector<T>::intercambiar_monticulos(int vect[MAX],int i,int j)
{
    aux=vect[i];
    vect[i]=vect[j];
    vect[j]=aux;
}
//revisar para comparaciones si no fuciona
template <class T>
void operaciones_vector<T>::monticulos()
{
    //Meto los datos en el monticulo (ordeno)
    for(i=tamano;i>=0;i--)
    {
        filtrado_desc_monticulos(vect,i,tamano);
        //Saco los datos y los meto al final para obtener el array ordenado
        for(i=tamano-1;i>0;i--)
        {
            intercambiar_monticulos(vect,0,i);
            filtrado_desc_monticulos(vect,0,i-1);
        }
    }
}

template <class T>
void operaciones_vector<T>::mergesort()
{
    int aux[tamano];
    ord_intercalacion(vect,aux,0,tamano-1);
}

template <class T>
void operaciones_vector<T>::ord_intercalacion(int vect[MAX], int aux[MAX], int izq, int der)
{
    if(izq<der)
    {
        /* este if comprueba el caso base que es cuando la particion pasada no tiene elementos. */
        /* dividimos a la mitad el sub array [A[izq],...,A[der]] */
        int centro=(izq+der)/2;

        /* aplicamos la recursiÛn en ambas mitades */
        ord_intercalacion (vect, aux, izq, centro);
        ord_intercalacion (vect, aux, centro+1,der);

        /* a este punto ambas mitades deberÌan estar ordenadas por lo que las intercalamos para unirlas en una sola secuencia ordenada. */
        intercalar(vect,aux,izq,centro+1,der);
    }
}

template <class T>
void operaciones_vector<T>::intercalar(int vect[MAX], int aux[MAX], int izq, int centro, int der)
{
    /* mis particiones ser·n [izq,...,centro-1] y [centro,...,der] */

    /* contadores para la primera mitad, la segunda y para la intercalacion respectivamente. */

    int ap=izq, bp=centro, cp=izq;

    while((ap<centro)&&(bp<=der))
    {
        if(vect[ap]<=vect[bp])
        {
            aux[cp]=vect[ap];
            ap++;
        }
        else
        {
            aux[cp]=vect[bp];
            bp++;
        }
        cp++;
    }
    /* terminamos de intercalar, ahora metemos los elementos restantes de la lista que a˙n no ha terminado de ser procesada. */
    while(ap<centro)
    {
        aux[cp]=vect[ap];
        cp++;
        ap++;
    }
    while(bp<=der)
    {
        aux[cp]=vect[bp];
        cp++;
        bp++;
    }
    /* ahora que tenemos la intercalaciÛn finalizada en tmp, la pasamos a vect */
    for (ap = izq; ap <= der; ap++)
    {
        vect[ap] = aux[ap];
    }
}

template <class T>
void operaciones_vector<T>::quicksort()
{
    ord_rapida(vect,0,tamano-1);
}

template <class T>
void operaciones_vector<T>::ord_rapida(int vect[MAX], int izq, int der)
{
    /* se trabaja en el subarray [A[izq],...,A[der]] */
    if(der-izq>1) /* caso base de la recursiÛn */
    {
        /* elegimos el pivote y lo ponemos en A[der-1] */
        int centro = (izq+der)/2;
        if (vect[izq]>vect[centro])

            //intercambiar(vect,izq,centro);

            if (vect[izq]>vect[der])

                //intercambiar(vect,izq,der);

                if(vect[centro]>vect[der])

                    //intercambiar(vect,centro,der);
                    //intercambiar(vect,centro,der-1);
                {
                    //Particionamos

                    pivote=vect[der-1];
                    do
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            izq++;
                        }
                        while(vect[izq]<pivote);
                        do
                        {
                            der = der - 2;
                        }
                        while(vect[der-1]>pivote);
                        //intercambiar(vect,izq,der-1);
                    }
                    while(der-1>1);
                    /* deshacemos el ˙ltimo intercambio el cual se efectuÛ sin cumplirse i<j */
                    //intercambiar(vect,izq,der-1);
                    /* ponemos el pivote en el medio de ambas particiones */
                    //intercambiar (vect, izq, der - 1);
                    /*aplicamos la recursiÛn en las particiones halladas */
                    ord_rapida (vect, izq, izq - 1);
                    ord_rapida (vect, izq + 1, der);
                }
    }
}

template <class T>
void operaciones_vector<T>::ord_ma()
{
    CORTE=log(tamano)*log(tamano);
    ord_rapida(vect,0,tamano-1);
    insercion();
};

template <class T>
void operaciones_vector<T>::ord_indi()
{
    ptr_i=vect;

    for(i=1;i<=tamano;i++)
    {
        ptr_j=ptr_i;
        for(j=i;j<tamano;j++)
        {
            if(*ptr_i>*ptr_j)
            {
                aux=*ptr_i;
                *ptr_i=*ptr_j;
                *ptr_j=aux;
            }
            *(ptr_j++);
        }
        *(ptr_i++);
    }
}

template <class T>
void operaciones_vector<T>::busqueda_secuencial()
{
    do
    {
        int b=0;
        cout << "Numero a buscar: ";
        cin >> numero;

        for(i = 1 ; i <= tamano ; i++)
        {
            if (numero == vect[i] )
            {
                cout << numero << " Se encuentra en la posicion " << i << endl;
                b=1;
            }
        }

        if(b == 0)
            cout << numero << " No se encontro" << endl;
        do
        {
            cout << "Deseas Buscar otro Numero?(S/N)";
            cin >> respuesta;

            respuesta = toupper(respuesta);
        }while(respuesta != 'S' && respuesta != 'N');
    }while(respuesta == 'S');
};

template <class T>
void operaciones_vector<T>::busqueda_binaria()
{
    int inf,sup,mit,dato;
    cout<<"Dato a buscar: ";
    cin>>dato;
    inf=0;
    sup=tamano;
    while (inf<=sup)
    {
        mit=(inf+sup)/2;
        if (vect[mit]==dato)
        {
            cout<<dato<<" Se encontro en la posicion "<<mit+0<<endl;
            break;
        }
        if (vect[mit]>dato)
        {
            sup=mit;
            mit=(inf+sup)/2;
        }
        if (vect[mit]<dato)
        {
            inf=mit;
            mit=(inf+sup)/2;
        }
    }
    cout<<"\n\n"<<endl;
}

template <class T>
void operaciones_vector<T>::burbuja_mejorada()
{
    for(i=1; i<=tamano; i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j<=tamano; j++)
        {
            if(vect[i]<vect[j])
            {
                aux=vect[i];
                vect[i]=vect[j];
                vect[j]=aux;
            }
        }
    }
}



template <class T>
void operaciones_vector<T>::menu()
{
    //system("cls");
    cout<<"\t\tM E N U   V E C T O R \n\n"     <<endl
    <<"1. Llenar Vector"                       <<endl
    <<"2. Imprimir Vector"                     <<endl
    <<"3. Ordenar Vector"                      <<endl
    <<"4. Buscar dato en el vector"            <<endl
    <<"5. Fin"                                 <<endl
    <<"\n6. Imprimir una carita feliz (como io)" <<endl
    <<"7. Imprimir una carita triste (como tu)" <<endl
    <<"\nOpcion: ";
}

int main()
{
    system("Color 0A");
    int op;
    class operaciones_vector<int> v;

    //
    //v.color();
    v.color(1);

    while(1)
    {
        system("cls");
        v.menu();
        cin>>op;
        switch(op)
        {
            case 1:
                //sobrecarga ./.

                v.Vector::llenado();
                system("Pause");
                break;

            case 2:
                v.Vector::impresion();
                system("Pause");
                break;

            case 3:
                //ya incluye todos los tipos :v
                v.Vector::ordenamiento(); // <-- Polimorfismo sobrecarga
                v.ordenamiento();
                system("Pause");
                break;

            case 4:
                v.busqueda();
                system("Pause");
                break;

            case 5:
                v.alv();
                break;

            case 6:
                cout<<" c: "<<endl;
                system("Pause");
                break;

            case 7:
                cout<<" :c "<<endl;
                system("Pause");
                break;
            default:
                cout<<"Opcion no valida :c"<<endl;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta y presenta un ejemplo mínimo que reproduzca el problema... ¿nos tenemos que leer 790 líneas para entender el problema?

Comment: ¿En qué línea te sale el error indicado?

Comment: el fallo sale en todas las lineas de bucles.. no le falta poner que `i` es `int`? ej: `for( int a = ...`

Answer (score 4):

Los errores son bastante legibles:

**error 1**

Mensaje:

```
prog.cc:187:37: warning: unused parameter 'n' [-Wunused-parameter]
void operaciones_vector<T>::color(T n)
                                    ^
```

Realmente no es un error sino una advertencia... no estás haciendo uso del parámetro `n`. Si vas a la función es facil ver el problema:

```
template <class T>
void operaciones_vector<T>::color(T n)
//                                  ^ Declaras n...
{
    system("Color 0A"); // ... pero n no se usa en ninguna parte
}
```

**error 2**

Mensaje:

```
prog.cc:288:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'i'
    for(i=1 ; i <= tamano ; i++)
        ^
```

Otra vez mensaje claro como el solo (y mira que los mensajes de C++ pueden ser ilegibles cual lengua alienígena, pero no es el caso)... estás usando una variable, `i` que **no está declarada**. Vamos a copiar la función para que quede más claro:

```
template <class T>
void operaciones_vector<T>::impresion()
{
    cout<<"I m p r i m i r"<<endl;
    for(i=1 ; i <= tamano ; i++)
    //  ^     ^             ^ ¿Donde esta declarada la variable?
    {
        cout << "Vect["<<i<<"]= " << *(vector+i) << endl;
    }
}
```

Declaras la variable y adios error:

```
for(int i=1 ; i <= tamano ; i++)
//  ^^^
```

**error 3**

```
prog.cc:288:24: error: use of undeclared identifier 'tamano'
    for(int i=1 ; i <= tamano ; i++)
                       ^
```

Otra variable no declarada... y esta encima ha sido a drede:

```
template <class T>
class operaciones_vector: public Vector<T>//, public comandos_basicos <T>
{

protected:
    T vect [MAX];
    T aux,dato;
    T k,cont,op,opc2;
    T izq, centro,der;
    T pivote;
    T *ptr_i, *ptr_j;

    /*T tamano;     //Determina el tamanio del vector <<-----
    T *vector;    //Pues el vector :v
    T i;          //un contador
    T j;          //otro contador
    T auxiliar;   //ayuda a ordenar el vector
    T numero;     //Ayuda a buscar el numero
    char respuesta; //Tonteria de validacion*/
```

Es decir, la variable estaba declarada pero **la has comentado**...

---

Llegados a este punto decido parar de corregir mensajes.

Coge un manual de C++ y ponte las pilas. No te pongas a trabajar con plantillas si no conoces los fundamentos básicos del lenguaje y, si resulta que es una practica de clase y tienes que hacerla entonces más te vale rezar porque el toro te ha cogido a base de bien. Dicho de otra forma: "C++ no es un lenguaje que se controle en 2 horas y has tenido todo un curso para aprender lo basico... en el examen no habrá nadie de StackOverflow ni de ningun otro foro así que ponte a estudiar C++ como si tu vida dependiese de ello porque, en cierto modo, es así)